# Postgresql function to create table in other database

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I Want a function to create Table in the different database , Database name is the argument for the function and table structure and names are static {No need to pass as the arguments}

Comment: even from "postgres" database ??

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is possible using dblink, isn't it?

Comment: Are you aware of schemas? Most people who're trying to do this sort of thing are attempting it to do multi-tenant storage. If you *ever* think you might need to then query these tables between databases, stop what you're doing now and and use separate schemas in the same database instead.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`dblink`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) extension, this is possible.

Just create a connection inside your function, supplying the database name:

```
SELECT dblink_connect('conn', format('hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5435 dbname=%I user=test password=test', 'foreign_test'));
SELECT dblink_exec('conn', 'CREATE TABLE t (id integer)');
SELECT dblink_disconnect('');
```

Note that using the `format()` function escapes your database name as necessary.